# CMS для github-pages

Tags: html, github, cms, github-pages

Гидхаб любезно предоставил хостинг для моего проекта - "github-pages".
Но редакция, особенно добавление "элементов" в каталог "Список переведённой манги" очень неудобная, так как нужно полностью перезаливать html файл.
Можно ли подключить cms для удобной редакции?
Прикреплю сайт для понимания: https://tfoxs.github.io/tfoxs/
Спасибо за внимание.

Comment: Ну можно использовать jekyll, каталог реализовать через шаблон, куда будет заполняться список "постов". Сами посты в виде markdown, который будет преобразовываться в html и подставляться в нужный html шаблон.

Comment: insolor, спасибо за информацию. Обязательно посмотрю.